# Facebook Bot messenger line break at 300 character

Tags: node.js, facebook-messenger, botframework

I am new in node js development. I have develop an fb messenger bot with microsoft bot builder library. When I reply to user then my sentence get's break after 300 character.Please help me on the same.[image]

Comment: The Facebook Messenger API for text messages has a limit of 320 characters. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/text-message

Comment: Thanks for the info Facundo, I want to check is there any alternate way available to extends the limit?

Answer (score 0):

You can split these text blocks on the proposals, and implement the simple template engine - handle new lines, dots, numbered lists. Add handling to the custom markers for the indivisible group of the proposals. Something like "blah blah. | blah. blah. | blah blah blah."

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook Messenger API for text messages has a limit of 600 to 640 characters.
If the message exceeds the limit then message get's break from that length and new message received in messenger.
Please refer the link for more details,
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/text-message